# show-csv returning no results in Aviarc

Tags: sql, aviarc

I'm using show-csv to serve the results of a report to the user. When I run this query directly against the database, it returns the correct results:

```
SELECT *
FROM ticket
WHERE date_raised >= '2011-01-01'
AND date_raised <= '2011-06-30'
AND severity = 3
ORDER BY problem_no
```

But when run the query based on parameters it executes and gives me a file with no results:

```
<show-csv query="get-range-csv" filename="{$query.filename}">
    <param name="start-date" value="{$query.start-date}" />
    <param name="end-date" value="{$query.end-date}" />
    <param name="severity" value="{$query.severity}" />
</show-csv>

SELECT *
FROM ticket
WHERE date_raised >= {$start-date}
AND date_raised <= {$end-date}
AND severity = {$severity}
ORDER BY problem_no
```

Relevant screen code:

```
<container position="relative" height="46">
    <container left="0">
        <text-static left="0" width="80" text="Start date:" />
        <date-select field="query.start_date" left="80" />
    </container>
    <container left="210">
        <text-static left="0" width="70" text="End date:" />
        <date-select field="query.end_date" left="70" />
    </container>
</container>
```

Any ideas why I'm not getting any results from ?

I've run this through the debugger and the query dataset variables are set correctly when  runs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that the screen is using start_date and end_date (with underscores) whereas the show-csv command is using start-date and end-date (with dashes).